# default migration group in Octopus gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sharding, octopus

i'm trying to understand how the default migration group on octopus gem really work. Been googling around, there isn't really much info about this part of the gem. Any help would be really appreciated.

**shards.yml**

```
octopus:
  default_migration_group: db_list
  environments:
    - development
  development:
    db1:
      adapter: mysql2
      database: db1
      username: root
      password:
      host: localhost
    db2:
      adapter: mysql2
      database: db2
      username: root
      password:
      host: localhost
```

rake db:migrate only updates the database which is defined in the database.yml file

Answer (score 0):

So the purpose of the Octopus is to allows a rails application to run multiple instances of a database. So the purpose of Database Sharding provides is that it provides a method for scalability across independent servers, each with their own CPU, memory and disk. Basic example of Database Sharding is very straightforward: take a large database, and break it into a number of smaller databases across servers which will look something like this: [Image of sharding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzfaP.png). Core advantage of sharding is that it increases scalability.

In the above example of what you have there. You could take a particular "client/company" that belongs to a particular server `foo.company.com` now you don't want to share this companies data with lets say your main database. So in this scenario you can restrict your rails application to say okay. When `foo.company.com` is accessed I want to target this `foo_prod` database for example. Also when you break your databases down it makes it easier to manage and also from a security perspective it would be safer not to have your "clients/companies" data all munged together.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the explanation but at the end after adding **using_group(:test)** to every migration and making appropriate changes in shard.yml as describe in docs,  we cut the migration time on all of the servers from almost 6h to around ~25 minutes.

At the end I couldn't figure out how to make **default_migration_group: db_list** work, so i just wrote a small script that added **using_group(:test)** to all of the existing migrations and made changes to migration generator so that all of the new migrations would have that method in them.